# Do these two random variables have the same asymptotic distribution?

Tags: asymptotics, central-limit-theorem, asymptotic-covariance

Let $\{X_k\}$ be a sequence of dependent random variables with mean 0. Define $\bar{Y}_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$.

Let $\{W_k\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean 1 and variance 1. Define $\bar{Z}_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt k}\sum_{i=1}^k W_i X_i$.

It is known that $\bar{Y}_k \implies \mathcal{N}(0,V)$, where $\implies$ denotes convergence in distribution, and $V$ is some covariance matrix.

Can we also say that $\bar{Z}_k$ converges to the same distribution? How would one prove this rigorously? And does this imply that $\bar{Y}_k$ and $\bar{Z}_k$ are asymptotically equivalent, in some sense?'

The main problem I see here is the dependence in the sequence $\{X_k\}$. If they were i.i.d., then the variance of the sum becomes the sum of variances, and the proof becomes straightforward.

Comment: It is not generally true that the standardized average of dependent random variables converge to a normal. Furthermore, $V$ is not a covariance matrix. It is just a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no.

For example, suppose $A_k$ are iid $N(0,1)$ and $B_k$ are also iid $N(0,1)$ and $X_{2k}=A_k+B_k$, $X_{2k+1}= A_k-B_k$.  Then the $B_k$ all cancel and
$$\bar Y_{2k}= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2k}}\sum_k A_k\sim N(0, 2)$$

Suppose $W_k$ is binary with values 0 and 2. Instead of the $B_k$  all cancelling, about half of them will be present once, and the variance of $\bar Z$ will be larger than that of $\bar Y$.

**Update**: more generally, the $W_kX_k$ are *uncorrelated*,
$$\mathrm{var}[\bar Z_k] = \frac{1}{k}\sum_k \mathrm{var}[W_kX_k]=\frac{1}{k}\sum_k \mathrm{var}[X_k]$$

Independence (or at least exchangeability) actually matters for these multiplier results; it's not just a technical convenience.

Comment: Are you sure about the assertion you make in the "Update" section? It appears that what you write would be correct if $E(W) = 0$. But the OP assumes that $E(W)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the $X_k$'s are jointly independent and identically distributed (with zero mean), so are the $W_k$'s (with mean equal to unity and variance equal to unity as are the premises), and they are also jointly independent in between them.

Then
$${\rm var}[\bar{Z}_k] = {\rm var}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\sum_{i=1}^k W_i X_i\right] = \frac1 k \sum_{i=1}^k {\rm var}[W_i X_i] = {\rm var}[WX]. $$

Now,

$${\rm var}[WX] = E\left[WX\right]^2 - \left(E[WX]\right)^2 = E\left[W^2X^2\right] - \left(E[WX]\right)^2.$$

Due to full independence we can separate expected values,
$$E\left[W^2X^2\right] = E\left[W^2\right] E\left[X^2\right], \; {\rm and}\; E[WX] = E[W]E[X].$$

By the premises, $E[X] =0$, so the second component vanishes. Also, because again $E[X] = 0$, we have that ${\rm var}[X] = E[X^2]$. So we arrive at

$${\rm var}[WX] = E[W^2] {\rm var}[X].$$

Now, and since $E[W]=1$,
$${\rm var}[W] \equiv E[W^2] - \left(E[W]\right)^2 = E[W^2] - 1 \implies E[W^2] = 1 + {\rm var}[W].$$

So we obtain

$${\rm var}[WX] = \left(1+{\rm var}[W]\right) \cdot {\rm var}[X] \neq {\rm var}[X].$$

For ${\rm var}[W]=1$ we get
$${\rm var}[\bar{Z}_k] = {\rm var}[WX] = 2{\rm var}[X].$$

So, **the side answer is "no, even if we had full independence, $\bar{Z}_k$ does not have the same variance as $\bar{Y}_k$"** (the latter's variance being just ${\rm var}[X]$).